# bootstrap carousel slider ID of items appears in URL

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

bootstrap carousel slider id appears in URL . like It shows in the following pictures[image]

[image]

it changes sliders but it shows the ID of Each slide item in the URL.

I changed the version of Jquery for newer version, that is happened

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the previous version of your Jquery.

Comment: thank you mr.Majid, but I want to use the newest version, but I had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `href=" "` use `data-target=" "` and it will work fine.